# "Then" is not executed after the Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to coordinate the test of a database with the close. First, I want to do the test and then close the connection and show a test. But, I only get to do the test and not the close.

I have a class where I managed the connection with MySQL, in the file "db.js":

```
import Sequalize from "sequelize";
import config from "./config";

class MySQLConnector {
    constructor(){
        this.db = new Sequalize(config.ddbb_connection.database, config.ddbb_connection.user,
        config.ddbb_connection.password, {
            host: config.ddbb_connection.host,
            dialect: "mysql",
            operatorsAliases: false,
            pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                acquire: 30000,
                idle: 10000
            }
        }) 
    };

    test(){
        this.db.authenticate().then(() => {
            console.log("Connection to database: " + config.ddbb_connection.database + 
            " has been established succesfully");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Unable to connect to database: " + err);
        }); 
    };

    closeConnection(){
        this.db.close();
        console.log("Connection to database: " + config.ddbb_connection.database + 
        " has been closed!!!");
    }
};

module.exports.MySQLConnector = MySQLConnector;
```

And I have another file "index.js" where I try to make the test and then close the connection:

```
import express from "express";
import config from "./config";
import {MySQLConnector} from "./db";

const app = express();
let db = new MySQLConnector();
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    db.test();
});

myPromise.then(()=>{
    db.closeConnection();
}).catch(()=>{
    console.log("Don't do anything!!!");
});

app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
    console.log("Server " + config.server.name + " listening on port " + config.server.port);
});
```

But, the only thing that I get is to make the test and not close the connection. You can check the result in this screen capture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

If I call "then" when a create the promise, it doesn't works. I've got the same result.

```
let db = new MySQLConnector();
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    db.test();
}).then(()=>{
    db.closeConnection();
});
```

**Edit II:**

Thank you to @CertainPerformance to give me the correct solution!!!.

My code finally is

**db.js:**

```
import Sequalize from "sequelize";
import config from "./config";

class MySQLConnector {
    constructor(){
        this.db = new Sequalize(config.ddbb_connection.database, config.ddbb_connection.user,
        config.ddbb_connection.password, {
            host: config.ddbb_connection.host,
            dialect: "mysql",
            operatorsAliases: false,
            pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                acquire: 30000,
                idle: 10000
            }
        }) 
    };

    test(){
       return this.db.authenticate().then(() => {
            console.log("Connection to database: " + config.ddbb_connection.database + 
            " has been established succesfully");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Unable to connect to database: " + err);
        }); 
    };

    closeConnection(){
        this.db.close();
        console.log("Connection to database: " + config.ddbb_connection.database + 
        " has been closed!!!");
    }
};

module.exports.MySQLConnector = MySQLConnector;
```

**index.js:**

```
import express from "express";
import config from "./config";
import {MySQLConnector} from "./db";

const app = express();
let db = new MySQLConnector();
db.test().then(() => db.closeConnection());

app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
    console.log("Server " + config.server.name + " listening on port " + config.server.port);
});
```

The result what I get is what I expect!!! First I make the test, then I close the connection.

[image]

Comment: You have to call `resolve` and/or `reject` explicitly when creating a `new Promise` through a callback

Comment: Thank you @SrThompson but it doesn't work. I have edit my post with the result of your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `index.js` you're constructing a Promise but never calling its `resolve` function, so it never resolves. But there's no need for the Promise constructor here: simply have `test` return the Promise chained from `authenticate`:

```
test(){
  return this.db.authenticate().then(() => {
  // ...
```

and then in `index.js`:

```
db.test()
  .then(() => db.closeConnection());
```

If you *did* use the Promise constructor method (which you *definitely shouldn't* because you already have a Promise, but just for information), `index.js` would look like this, calling the `resolve` argument so as to resolve the Promise once `test` is done:

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  db.test()
    .then(resolve);
});

myPromise.then(()=>{
  db.closeConnection();
}).catch(()=>{
  console.log("Don't do anything!!!");
});
```